# Delay auto_open macro with option to cancel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently developing a macro which I will eventually use to import data from the web on a daily basis, which will activate when the excel file is opened. The data is only relevant after a certain time of day and I will be using task scheduler to automatically open the file after this time.

The only problem is that I don't want the macro to run when I open the file manually, and I'm therefore wondering if it is possible to put a delay timer on the macro, with the added ability to stop the macro from executing during this period. Or if there are any other possible solutions to this problem.

Cheers all

Comment: Try opening it with disabled Macro option.

Comment: I assume you're talking about holding down shift when opening from within Excel? I had to look this up as I've never had cause to use it until now. Is that the only way? As inevitably there will be the day that I forget to do this and make a mess of my data.

Comment: You don't have to put your data import script in worksheet_open, You can run it and any macro using VBS automation, then schedule Task  manager to run the **get_data.VBS** file script instead.

Comment: how do you know when the data on the web is relevant? maybe the script can check for that.

Comment: Tsion.D.P - That's a bit above my head, although the VBA script does more than just import data so I don't know if that would still work either way. jsotola - I'm importing stock prices so it's impossible to know what they will be; the rest of the information will look the same unfortunately. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a msgbox when you open workbook.

- If you click Cancel, code will not run.
- If you click OK, code will
  run.
- If you don't do anything for 5 secs (task scheduler), code will
  run.

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim msg As String, runcode As Long

msg = "Click cancel to abort or the code will execute in 5 seconds!"
runcode = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Popup(msg, 5, "What to do:", vbOKCancel)

If runcode = 2 Then End

'call import data macro
End Sub
```

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: Sorry to revive this but although this worked yesterday it no longer seems to be working with no material change to the code. The message box still appears but it doesn't go away after ten seconds. Anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: @andimac It is said to be a bug for the 'Timeout' on the WsShell.Popup function, it sometimes malfunctions.  If it is not working for you, you can make your own userform and unload it after 5 secs as well. Sounds good?

Comment: There's a lot I have yet to learn about VBA - unfortunately your suggestion is one of those things! Is it a straight forward process for you to put it on here?

Comment: There are lots of tuts on the internet regarding userform. [Here](http://www.contextures.com/xlUserForm01.html) is one of them. Once you create your own Msgbox, you are welcome to come here and ask another question regarding your issues.